# Storing functions and sub procedures in separate class file

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering how to have an external class file from the application.  Whenever I create a separate class file in Visual Studio, it seems it's only for my personal benefit of keeping the coding organized, but it still is stored inside the application(.exe) file.  I'm looking to have a separate file that contains most of my sub procedures and functions, so that when I update my application, it would only update that file instead of the actual .exe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do this by creating a Class Library.  The Library builds an assembly (DLL) that can be added as a reference to any Application, and then those types can be used by the Application.

Comment: I find this situation amusing.  We have the student, a mere level one experience, learning from the master, a 250k behemoth (highest score I've seen on SO)

Comment: @RussellUhl That's what's great about StackOverflow in general :D

Comment: I think I kind of understand, I think one of the problems was that, I was creating classes inside of the program.  Sorry if I come off like an idiot, I don't really program other than in my spare time and every so often.  But I've seemed to of created a class separate from the application now, but I'm not sure how to import it properly and not really sure how to turn it in to a DLL.  I don't mean to waste you're time and I definitely appreciate the help!

Comment: @user2501947 You'd create the classes in a "Class Library" project, then add a "reference" to that project or the DLL generated.  See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RA9Q89AaJ8

Comment: Thanks!  That helped a lot!  It wasn't creating the DLL file when I would add the classes with the program open, but that video helped a lot.  Thank you much!

Comment: Note that you can use one solution file containing both the application project and the class library project.  You don't need to have each project be in its own separate solution (though you can do so).